# Android: Arraylist is not cleared using clear() method in DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I request you to solve my problem. Some phones are giving me problem to clear Array list. I used`"arrayList.clear()"`method to clear the Array list. It  works good in my phone but my client phone give problem. Data in list is show twice in my client's phone. But in my phone it show one time. It gives problem in my client's phone. Can anyone give me solution. Thanks in advance.

In below code when you select date then Array list is cleared and run a class to download data from API. Every time when you select date Array list is cleared and run class again. For this code give me solution for upper error i mention you.

```
public void daatepopup() {
    DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(ResultChartActivity.this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    tvDate.setText(year + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + dayOfMonth);
                    date = tvDate.getText().toString();
                    if (date.equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(ResultChartActivity.this, "Select Date For Result Chart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        if (NetworkAvailablity.chkStatus(ResultChartActivity.this)) {
                            arrayList.clear();
                            new GetResultChart().execute();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ResultChartActivity.this, "Check Internet Connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, year, month, day);
    d.show();
}
```

Comment: is Arraylist belongs to list view if yes and you want to change listview data then you have to call youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after arraylist.clear(); else edit question with more detail related to problem

Comment: thanks for your support.